# .htaccess rewrite for user profile page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I want the following:

When a user types in browser: `mydomain/user/their_username`
I want that the user gets to see his profile page. The profile page is a page called user.php in my root directory. The user.php file needs a `$user` var set. So when user.php gets requested, the url should be: mydomain/user.php?user=their_username

So from `mydomain/user/their_username to mydomain/user.php?user=their_username`

The user is only allowed to enter a to z (capitals are allowed), numbers and an underscore. Anything else should redirect them to an error page. Also, their should be no error if the user types in a slash at the end.

What should I put in my htaccess file?

(I am using xampp to test my code)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read any tutorials on htaccess and how you might start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)[/]?$ user.php?user=$1
```

Comment: This works, but I found another (better) way. Thanks anyway :)